# Apply a default sort column in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

This seems like a really stupid question, but I can't work it out! How do I programmatically apply a sort order to an ObjectListView? My code is very straight forward:

```
listOfItems.Add(new ListItem(a, b, c, d));
listOfItems.Add(new ListItem(e, f, g, h));
objectListView.SetObjects(listOfItems);
```

But it's at this point I want to enforce sorting on, say, "column 3 ascending" and I cannot for the life of me find a way to do it!

I don't want to do anything fancy, just programmatically simulate the effect of the user clicking the column 3 header until it's sorted ascending.

Comment: have you looked at http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-do-some-fancy-sorting?

Comment: I have - as I say, I don't want to do fancy sorting. I just want to default a sort order without the user having to click anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its pretty straightforward, maybe you just missed it:

```
objectListView1.Sort(targetColumn, SortOrder.Ascending);
```

This would use the default sorting or the CustomSorter (if implemented) for the specified column.

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: When I said it was a stupid question, I didn't realise just HOW stupid until I saw your answer! I searched and searched and clearly could not see the wood for the trees. How embarrassing! Works great and kudos given - many thanks for taking the time to respond.